# mysql not started in windows

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have started mysql in xampp but this I get after installing mysql-server in port 3306

```
 Problem detected!
    15.29.09  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MYSQL57"!
    15.29.09  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
    15.29.09  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
    15.29.09  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: It seems `port` is already in use. Try to find the service using it or reconfigure `mysql` to start in another one.

Comment: how can I get another port?

Comment: In `wampsever` is `right click -> tools -> Use a port other tan 3306`